# How to use/install GNU binutils (objdump)

Tags: windows, cygwin, gnu, binutils, objdump

I need to use the objdump and readelf commands in my application that runs on windows. I know I can install cygwin in order to use them. The reason why I don't want to use cygwin is because I want to make it essay to deploy. Plus I don't know how to make a silent install of cygwin. As a result I believe that what I need is [GNU Utilities For Win32](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-command-line-utilities-for-windows/) as the link states those libraries are serverless. "executables do only depend on the Microsoft C-runtime (msvcrt.dll) and not an emulation layer like that provided by Cygwin tools"

Anyways once I go to that link I don't know how to install it. **Specifically I will like to use [>this tool<](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)**

I will appreciate if someone can point me on the right direction of how I will be able to use objdump and readelf (binutils in cygwin) on my application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

they are already compiled and they can be downloaded from [here!](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/binutils/binutils-2.28/)

Once downloaded they will be located in the bin directory:

[image]

and then you will use it the same way you use it on linux by passing the same args.